# Error during update 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, updates

Noticed that the new LTS is out and got a notification pop-up, but when I try and upgrade it Comes up with the following:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then, when I click close it reverts any changes its made.
I have the update server as 'Main Server'.
Our internet connection is stable

concise `sources.list`: (i removed the double commented lines)

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/ lsb3.2 main # disabled on upgrade to xenial
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-security main restricted
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: added above. if you need the whole file with the double hashed lines then say

Comment: Ok, try replacing `ports` in the last two lines of `sources.list` with `archive` and then running the `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Actually, you could just comment out the second to last line and replace the `ports` with `archive` in the last line.

Comment: okay so now im getting `Err http://archive.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com xenial-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]` (sorry i cant get the formatting right on this )

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake.  Instead of `archive` or `ports`, put `security` in both lines.  If you commented out the line I told you to, uncomment it.  Sorry, that's my mistake.

Comment: okay about to try this. but slightly concerned that my ubuntu has gone pretty buggy and windows appears to have disappeared off my bootloader after the last `apt-get upgrade` i did...oh well i was gonna remove it anyway

Comment: so it should read `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ xenial-security main restricted`? still getting 404s on them

Comment: Wait, you're missing a `ubuntu` right aftoer `ubuntu.com/`.  Try adding that, maybe?

Comment: BTW, don't shut off your computer.

Comment: too late >.< but i dont know if this is progress but with `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted` im now getting a lot of `W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libxapian-dev'
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max` in the console on the `sudo apt-get update` call

Comment: starting to think itll be simpler for me to format my hdd in the morning and just clean install everything. but ill keep at this for a bit because its not ideal to format

Comment: okay, nevermind. when i loaded into tty it said i had 16.04 installed. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Sorry I didn't get back.  You could probably actually comment out the last two lines and run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` just to make sure everything is totally up-to-date.

Comment: @anonymous2 done :) unfortunately i had to spend another hour or 2 trying to figure out fglrx and stuff but its sorted now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
Enter the follow commands in a Terminal

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The first command will delete your local repo cache (it seems sometimes they can get into an inconsistent state) and apt-get update will refresh the whole thing from source.

Comment: tried this but returned with the same errors in the console on `sudo apt-get update`